# Heading ::after element always in top right right after text

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have my heading with arrow ::after element. After element is positioned absolute with margin-left:10px, but when i shrink down website the element wraps with text down.

[image]

Is there a way for arrow to always stick to top right of heading no matter what width of device like this?

[image]

Tried with display inline but it doesnt work. Any idea if it's possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like ```<div>Looking for help<sup>></sup></div>``` ?

Comment: Position the heading as relative, add padding right to it. Position the pseudo-element as absolute, with top and right values.

Comment: Basically yes but i want arrow to always stay on top right even if i shrink the window and the heading wraps to next line.

Comment: Please put your code into the question.

Comment: How important is it that the arrow is close to the text? The problem with positioning an after element is that on some viewport sizes you could get quite a gap between the text and the arrow because of the space to the right of the text as it wraps whole words.

Comment: it's actually the most important thing here. The text is centered and on some vieport sizes there is always some big gap. I dont know if there is a way to make it stick without gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wrap the heading in another element and use the `::after` pseudo-element of the parent. In my example, I used a `<div>` with `display: inline;`, and set the heading's margin-right to `1em` to account for the width of the `::after` element. My code probably isn't too different from yours, just uses different selectors.

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/the_Northway/pen/GRMyrLR

Edit: adding the Stack Snippet by suggestion - codepen is still useful to change screen size though.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
div h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  content: ">";
  color: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div><h3>Looking for help?</h3></div>
```

Comment: Note, it's better to [create a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5351721) than use off-site resources like CodePen, whenever possible.

Comment: Yeah it works but on some viewports based on whats typed in title there is a gap between heading and arrow. I'm trying to make it always stick to the heading.

Comment: That'll have something to do with the whitespace property and might not be possible with pure CSS. According to the box model, I believe that the whitespace would occupy the box after the text wraps. For that reason, I'd just figure out at what screen sizes it breaks and use a media query to adjust the positioning of the pseudo-element. I'm not even sure JS could help position that element *exactly* where the text wraps.

Comment: I thought so too but wanted to ask for sure. Anyway thanks for your time and answer :).

Comment: It would be possible with JS, if a little tedious. (Add characters to a dummy div until get to the div height expanding - then you know you've found the end of the first line). It's almost but not quite possible with just CSS using first-line pseudo element and background image to draw the arrow - but you don't get enough space to draw it properly.